# Is there a better way to join two corrugated pipes?

Tags: plumbing

I've got two pipes from my dishwasher underneath my sink that are for the water that drains out of it. The pipe join has recently started leaking. The join is shown in the picture below and my question is, is there a better way or a better fitting to do the pipe join?

[image: Leaking pipe connection]

Comment: Can you tell from which joint in the connection the water is leaking?

Comment: I'd be tempted to try Jubilee clips (AKA worm-drive hose clamp AKA screw-band) in place of those spring clips. YMMV. Maybe you need a slightly larger diameter pipe in the middle. AFAIK those corrugated hoses are designed to be pushed onto a tapered plastic connector, not regular copper pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In The Old Dart, extension kits typically include a suitable joining pipe and Jubilee-clips (rather than spring clips)

[image]

You can buy the connector separately ([e.g.](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/WASHING-MACHINE-DISHWASHER-DRAIN-HOSE-CONNECTOR-22MM-/200403347268))

Comment: Hm, never heard those referred to as "Jubilee", always have called them ["gear clamps"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hose_clamp#Screw.2Fband_.28Worm_Gear.29_clamps). (+1 because they're WAY more reliable connections than the clamp-style).  Of course, I also had to Google to confirm "The Old Dart" meant what I thought it probably meant.. Can never find my English to English translator when I need it.

Comment: The "connector" is a poly barbed coupler, and come in sizes ranging from 1/4" up to several inches. All of those can be purchased individually at any hardware or big box store.